# Task Position does not contain a definition Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app in xamrian forms app that needs ask for the gelocation permission and if granted it needs to get the geolocation data from the device and then put the geolocation coordinates into the forecast.io URL I am using the Geolocator plugin by James Montemagno as well as the PermissionsPlugin by James Montemagno I am getting the same error 2 times:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type       'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ReadyMo C:\Users\debroc1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App Mac\AppNAme\AppName\AppName\App\RadarHome.xaml.cs  74  Active

I can not run my app because of these 2 errors here's my forms code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
namespace AppName.Radar
{
    public interface MyLocationTracker
    {
        void ObtainMyLocation();
        event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> locationObtained;    
    }

    public interface MyLocationEventArgs
    {
        double lat { get; set; }
        double lng { get; set; }
    }      

    public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {
        public RadarHome()
        {
            MyLocationTracker msi;

            double BetaLat;
            double BetaLog;

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
            {

                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {

                    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) => {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ew.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();


                }

                else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                {
                    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();
                    msi.locationObtained += (object Jsender, MyLocationEventArgs je) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(je.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
                }

            }

            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            var position = locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);

            BetaLat = position.Latitude; //error here 
            BetaLog = position.Longitude; // same error here

            string str = string.Format("https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/Lat:{0} , Long: {1}", BetaLat, BetaLog);


            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(str);
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas on what i'm missing?

Comment: I'm guessing that `GetPositionAsync` returns a Task, and that's what the type of `position` is. Does using `position.Result.Latitude` work, as that's accessing the result of the task?

Answer (score 0):

`GetPositionAsync` returns a `Task<Position>`, so you'll need to wait on the async call to get the position, either by using `.Result` as @stuartd suggests, or:

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);
```

Be aware that using `.Result` could block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Task is a unit of asynchronous work that may be ran in a different thread. C# allows you to "await" a task to finish executing and unwrap the result.
Avoid using .Result at all cost as it will lock the current thread.
A more comprehensive explanation by Stephen Cleary [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

```
public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {

        private readonly CrossGeolocator _locator;
        private double BetaLat;
        private double BetaLog;

        public RadarHome()
        {
            MyLocationTracker msi;

            _locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            if (_locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
            {

                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {

                    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) => {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ew.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();


                }

                else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                {
                    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();
                    msi.locationObtained += (object Jsender, MyLocationEventArgs je) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(je.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
                }

            }

            _locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            GetPositionAsynchronously();

            string str = string.Format("https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/Lat:{0} , Long: {1}", BetaLat, BetaLog);

            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(str);
        }

        private async void GetPositionAsynchronously()
        {
            //will run asynchronously in a diff thread
            var position = await _locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);

            BetaLat = position.Latitude; //will work
            BetaLog = position.Longitude; // will work      
        }


    }
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed suggestion! when I try it in vs2015 I get 5 errors and can't build here's a link to those errors: https://gist.github.com/TeamBrainStorm/2f76940ced10a98a65f5df0c3b20a044